# Create Layer of pixels with value higher than 0.3

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, reclassify, function

I have code that suppose to calculte NDVI and calssify it according to the NDVI value.
I have tried to add a function that will create for me a new layer that will have only pixels with value higher than 0.3 but for some reason nothing happend.

This is my function:

```
//////try to create layers with the pixels in red
var PixelsCounLayers = listOfImages.map(function(img){
  var imageNDVI=image.select('NDVI');
  var grt03=imageNDVI.gt(0.3).selfMask().rename('0.3');
  var grt05=imageNDVI.gt(0.5).selfMask().rename('0.5');
  var grt07=imageNDVI.gt(0.7).selfMask().rename('0.7');

return image.set('grt03', grt03).set('grt05',grt05).set('grt07', grt07);
});
```

I have also tries another version:

```
for (var i in listOfNumbers){
  var imageNDVI=image.select('NDVI');
  var hotspot=imageNDVI.gt(0.3)
  .selfMask()
  .rename('hotspot03');
Map.addLayer(hotspot,{palette: 'FF0000'},i);}
```

But I have gotten error:

> 0: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'NDVI' did not match any bands.

and this is link to the full code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1b79ba01d16ebc343a35af8482f542d

I used the polygon of Osaka but you can use whatever polygon you want.

My end goal: to create and display new layer that contains only pixels with value higher than 0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with this code:

```
for (var i in listOfNumbers){
  var imageNDVI = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var hotspot=imageNDVI.gt(0.3)
  .selfMask()
  .rename('hotspot03');
Map.addLayer(hotspot,{palette: 'FF0000'},i);}
```